# Training a new Stanford part-of-speech tagger from within the NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I've trained a part-of-speech tagger for an uncommon language (Uyghur) using the Stanford POS tagger and some self-collected training data. I've been using the NLTK's `nltk.tag.stanford.POSTagger` interface to tag individual sentences in Python. This works well for most of my purposes: (running from `/usr/share/stanford-postagger`)

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
>>> uy = POSTagger('models/uyghur.tagger', 'stanford-postagger.jar')
>>> uy.tag('Men méning mantini yégenlikimni bilimen .'.split())
[[(u'Men', u'PN1s'), (u'm\xe9ning', u'PN1s.GEN'), (u'mantini', u'N-ACC'), (u'y\xe9genlikimni', u'Vt-PST.dir-1s2'), (u'bilimen', u'Vt-PRS-1s1'), (u'.', u'PUNCT')]]
```

I would like to do a ten-fold cross-validation to get a better sense of the accuracy of this tagger, i.e., use each tenth of my complete training data as test data for a tagger trained on the other nine-tenths of the data. Splitting the data set ten ways is no problem in Python, but I don't know if there's a way to train a new tagger from within Python. When I've done it, it's been from the command line using `java -mx1g -classpath /usr/share/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -props uyghurtagger.props`.

Is it possible to train a new Stanford tagger from within Python using the NLTK interface, or will I need to create it manually via the command line each time?

Comment: As far as I know the Stanford tagger interface is only for using the tagger. I'm not sure why you want to train it from within the nltk, but if it's just a question of automating the cross-validation process, you can always launch the java process from within python with the `subprocess` module. Is there a reason you aren't just doing it this way?

Comment: I believe NLTK just wraps a call to use the tagger, not any ways to train it.  I would echo the above comment and say the quickest simplest solution here is to just write some Python code to make command line calls.

Comment: Thank you both! I should have known I was approaching the problem from the wrong side…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was much simpler to implement than I had thought.

```
import subprocess32
subprocess32.call(
    ['java', '-mx1g', '-classpath',
     '/usr/share/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar',
     'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', '-props',
     'uyghurtagger.props'])
```

It's really just as simple as passing a list of the command line arguments to `subprocess32.call()`. (I am using `subprocess32` instead of `subprocess` per the recommendation in the [`subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)).